# Why closing the read end of the pipe preventing remaining code to execute?

Tags: operating-system, pipe

Why in the below code ,no output is being shown.When I comment the line : "close(pipefd1[0]);" ,then the code is working well,otherwise it's not printing even "checking" on the terminal.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    int pipefd1[2];
    char buff[100]="hey there";
    char be[100];
    pipe(pipefd1);
    close(pipefd1[0]);
    cout<<"checking";
    write(pipefd1[1],buff,100);
    close(pipefd1[1]);
    read(pipefd1[0],be,100);
    close(pipefd1[0]);
    cout<<be;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, though, is that you are writing to a pipe without a reader. Per [specification of POSIX `write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), when writing to a pipe with only one end open, an error should be raised:

> [EPIPE]
>
> An attempt is made to write to a pipe or FIFO that is not open for reading by any process, or that only has one end open. A SIGPIPE signal shall also be sent to the thread.

This error causes your program to terminate directly, which prevents the executing of the remaining code.

Since writing ot the standard output is most times buffered, the program does not have the time to flush the output, which made it looking as if the line with `cout << "checking";` was not executed. If you would have written `std::cout.flush();` after writing 'checking' to the output, you would have seen it on your terminal.